# Why does one LED light turn off/flicker when adjacent dimmer switch is at 100%

Tags: electrical, wiring, led

We have an LED light fixture over our kitchen island. After about 2 years of use, it just stopped working (when you turn the fixture on via dimmer switch you can hear a humming coming from the fixture, but the light does not come on at all—we installed a new driver). 2 professional electricians believe the issue is with the fixture itself.

I noticed today when preparing to take the fixture down to send back to the manufacturer that if the dimmer switch (located in same 2-switch wall plate)for a different set of can lights is on and I turn the fixture dimmer up to 100%, the can lights turn off.

Interested to know whether anyone has seen this or has any ideas about (1) whether that is a dangerous condition and (2) how to fix that issue.

Thanks!

Comment: That is an interesting situation and somewhat concerning. If you are comfortable with electric, take a look in the box with the dimmers. Something is most likely wrong. Possibly a wayward wire or something of that nature. Good Luck

Comment: Check your wiring. You should have the hot wire going to each dimmer and the output of each dimmer to its respective light. Is the fixture. Also be sure the ground connections are clean and twisted together tightly.